# Determine all possible permutations within a numberset that sums to a value less than or equal to a specified number

Tags: combinations, permutation, subset-sum

Conditions:

- For example N = {2,3}
- Maximum sum threshold = 64
- Theoretically, maximum element in a single sum would be 32 (e.g. SUM({2,2,2...2}) = 64)
- Numbers can repeat and order does matter (e.g. 2,3,2 and 2,2,3 are both valid)

Output:

```
SUM({2}) = 2
SUM({3}) = 3 
SUM({2,3}) = 5 
SUM({3,2}) = 5 
...
SUM({2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}) = 64 %(longest sum scenario)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a divide & conquer algorithm:

```js
function getPermutations(target, numbers) {
  if (target < 0) return 0
  if (target === 0) return 1
  
  return numbers.reduce(
    (sum, number) => sum + getPermutations(target - number, numbers),
    0
  )
}

const result = getPermutations(64, [2,3])
console.log(result)
```

However, the raw version is very inefficient, the complexity is 2^n. So to make it better we can add momoization to make the complexity just n.

```js
const memory = {}

function getPermutations(target, numbers) {
  if (memory[target]) return memory[target]
  if (target < 0) return 0
  if (target === 0) return 1
  
  const result = numbers.reduce(
    (sum, number) => sum + getPermutations(target - number, numbers),
    0
  )
  memory[target] = result
  return result
}

const result = getPermutations(64, [2,3])
console.log(result)
```